# Terms related to the structure of atom

Tags: quantum-chemistry, atoms, terminology

In my chemistry textbook, the chapter "*Structure of Atom*" deals with the old Bohr's model and the new Quantum mechanical model. But when I read the contents of the new model of atom, there were terms like *energy levels*, *shells* being repeated. I failed to understand the context. Moreover, Bohr's model has been discarded so why do we still talk about energy levels/ orbits in an atom?

Basically, I want a *satisfactory explanation* of these terms: **energy levels**, **orbits**, **sub orbits**, **shells**, **sub-shells**, **orbitals** and **principal quantum number** in accordance with the ***Quantum mechanical model of the atom***.

I tried to understand this from two other books but there too the distinction was vague.

I also read the contents of:

[Is there a difference between energy levels and electron shells?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57952/is-there-a-difference-between-energy-levels-and-electron-shells)

https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/electronic-structure-of-atoms#orbitals-and-electrons

PS: Please provide an answer keeping in mind that the questioner is a Grade 11 student.

Comment: There are no orbits, suborbits, and subshells in QM.

Comment: What is the problem with the common QM definition of shell, subshell etc?

Comment: So, does the book not provide definitions of those terms? Or are you confused about those terms?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32860/quantum-mechanical-model-of-atom-and-the-quantum-numbers https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18466/difference-between-shells-subshells-and-orbitals

Comment: @Greg I can't tell if that comment is directed at my comment or the OP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between shells, subshells and orbitals](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18466/difference-between-shells-subshells-and-orbitals)

Comment: @JonCuster both